# Problem in using firebase crashlytics sdk

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I want to use of firebase crashlytics sdk base on official document and i got this gradle sync failed :

> ERROR: Android dependency
>   'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.4.1' is set to
>   compileOnly/provided which is not supported

What can i do for solving this problem ...?

app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    // Add dependency
    implementation  'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'  // Crashlytics plugin

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`compileOnly` *is* the replacement — the equivalent configuration that is being deprecated is `provided`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations).

Comment: ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':  Could not resolve com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1.

Comment: @DanialNazari can you post your gradle where you add library

Comment: @Danial Nazari In my side work fine using   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }

Answer (score 1):

In your project-level build.gradle, update your google-services to version 3.1.2 or later, then add the Crashlytics repositories and dependency:

```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Add the following repositories:
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    maven {
       url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...

    // Check for v3.1.2 or higher
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'  // Google Services plugin

    // Add dependency
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'  // Crashlytics plugin

   }
  }


 allprojects {
   // ...

  repositories {
   // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
   google()  // Google's Maven repository
   // ...
  }
 }
```

In your app-level build.gradle, add the Crashlytics dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
// ...

// (Recommended) Add Analytics
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'

// Add dependency
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
}
```

Comment: I edit post and i added app and project level gradle , Did I miss something?